# Java Newbie - When to use it? Relating to Boxing/Unboxing I think

Tags: java

- Integer x = 5;
- Integer x = Integer.valueOf(5);

Is there any scenario where I would want to use the 2nd one specifically or is it redundant altogether and shouldn't not bother about it?

Comment: First one is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Both statements are equivalent.

The statement `Integer x = 5` would be compiled to

```
Integer x = Integer.valueOf(5);
```

The compiler will do that for you behind the scene, so the only difference is the number of character in source file.

Answer (score 1):

After Java 5 (because of autoboxing / unboxing) there is no difference except the first one is shorter.

Comment: This method also provide cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.